# Trying to make append text letter by letter

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

Hi I'm a newbie with JavaScript and Jquery. What I am trying to do here is to print the text passed in the onclick() function alphabet by alphabet using the setTimeout function. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

HTML

```
<div>
         <p id='myTxt'></p>
</div>
 <input type='button' value='Submit' onclick="imScrolling('Hello World!!', 500, 0, document.getElementById('myTxt'))">
```

My Script.js file

```
 function imScrolling(scrollTxt, interval, index, target)
    {
        //alert(scrollTxt + " " + interval + " " + scrollTxt.length + " " + index + " " + target.id);
       while(index < scrollTxt.length)
      {
         //alert(scrollTxt[index]);
         setTimeout(function (scrollTxt, interval, index, target)
                {
                   $('#myTxt').append(scrollTxt[index]);
                   }, interval);
         index++;       
       }
    }
```

Also, I have noticed that if I do not pass the parameters to the setTimeout(), then the parameters like index, interval are shown as undefined in the alert message? Why is it so?

Comment: word-by-word or letter-by-letter? You title is quite different from what you ask for in your Question...

Comment: Thanks Roko. Just changed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `setTimeout`. What you want is `setInterval`.

```
function imScrolling(scrollTxt, interval, index, target) {
    //alert(scrollTxt + " " + interval + " " + scrollTxt.length + " " + index + " " + target.id);

    var notawhileloop = setInterval(function () {
        //alert(scrollTxt[index]);
        $('#myTxt').append(scrollTxt[index]);
        index++;
        if (index == scrollTxt.length) {
            clearInterval(notawhileloop);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

[Working jsfiddle with your HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/hCyBN/2/).

**Edit:** Oops, forgot to stop the looping. Updated fiddle as well.

---

**Edit 2:** Found [a neat trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9982409/2817961) that makes it easy to do this with setTimeout as well.

```
function imScrolling(scrollTxt, delay, index, target) {
    while (index < scrollTxt.length) {
        setTimeout(appendLetter, index * delay, scrollTxt, index);
        index++;
    }
}
function appendLetter(scrollTxt, index) {
    $('#myTxt').append(scrollTxt[index]);
}
```

[See it working in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCyBN/5/). The trick is multiplying the `delay` by `index` (so first timeout is set at 0*500, second at 1*500, third at 2*500 etc). Hope this also demonstrates the passing of parameters.

Comment: Thanks Justin a quick question. Can you tell me, when i used the setTimeout function, why weren't the parameters accessible inside the function? The alert threw the notification as undefined.

Comment: @NarenSingh Ok I'm not sure if I understand your question exactly, but the parameters shouldn't be passed to the anonymous function, they should be passed to `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(func, delay, param1, param2)`.

Comment: @NarenSingh I updated the answer with a `setTimeout` version that shows the passing of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `setTimeout` is asynchronous but your function keeps running the `while` synchronously and so `setTimeout` is being set many times immediately. This is what I suggest:

```
function imScrolling(scrollTxt, interval, index, target)
{
   setTimeout(function (){
       $('#myTxt').append(scrollTxt[index]);
       if(index < scrollTxt.length){
        imScrolling(scrollTxt, interval, index+1, target);
       }
       }, interval);
}
```

This way, you will set the interval again after the first one fires and not "at the same time". [Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohONuDe/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I just gave this a shot, but it didn't quite work for me. Can you share  a jsfidle link? For e.g. if I add an alert in the setTimeout with the parameters, nothing happens.

Comment: Excuse me, I forgot to remove the parameters of the function inside ´setTimeout´. That function should not have parameters. I edited the answer and here's the demo: http://jsbin.com/ohONuDe/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try not use event attributes on HTML.

jQuery helps you with it.

Try:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <p id="myTxt"></p>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" id="your-button" /> 
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () // jquery dom ready
{
    $("#container")
        .on("click", "#your-button", function ()
        {
            var yourText = "Hello World!!".split('');

            for (var i = 0; i < yourText.length; i++)
            {
                $("#myTxt")
                    .append(yourText[i])
                    .append("<br/>"); // just to line break
            }
        }
});
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/willianduarte/fFC8Q/1/)

Comment: Thanks buddy. This is another great option!

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's start wth the function you call with setTimeout.

```
function (scrollTxt, interval, index, target) {
  $('#myTxt').append(scrollTxt[index]);
}
```

You have defined a function with 4 parameters that gets called at a later time. The problem is that the function given to setTimeout isn't passed any parameters when it's called, so inside the anonymous function scrollTxt, interval, index and target will be undefined.

To get over this issue you can use a closure. Inside the anonymous function you can use variables available in the scope the anonymous function is defined:

```
 var a = 5;
 function () {
    console.log(a); // 5
 }
```

There is one more issue. The variables used are the actual variables, not copies. So if you change the variable outside, the value inside the anonymous function will change as well:

```
var a = 5;
var f = function () {
  console.log(a);
}
a = 10;
f(); // outputs 10
```

The variable that changes for you is index. To get over that, you need to create a copy of it for each iteration. What better way to do that than to give it as parameter to a function?

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  setTimeout((function(new_i) {
     return function () {
       console.log(new_i);
     };
  })(i),100);
}
// outputs 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Apply this and you can easily solve your problem (and understand how you're solving it).

Comment: Hi Tobos, Can you please have a look at the edits I made above? The code quite didn't work for me. Thanks a lot again!!

Answer (score 0):

*[**> Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/AcINil/2/edit)*

```
function imScrolling(txt, intv, i, elID){

  var $el = $(elID),
      tot = txt.length,
      interv = setInterval(doIt, intv);   

  function doIt(){
    $el.append(txt[i++]);
    if(i==tot) clearInterval(interv);
  }
  
}
```

<sub>Now something interesting:</sub>

#### How to do it using the jQuery's *animation* method:

Instead of `setInterval`, if you want to control the total time that occurs to do the animation you can use
**`.animate()`** and it's **`step`** function:

*[**> Live demo** (3500ms)](http://jsbin.com/AcINil/8/edit)*

```
function imScrolling(txt, time, i, elID){
  
    $({c:i}).animate(
      {c:txt.length},{
       duration : time,
       easing : 'linear',
       step : function(now){
           d = ~~(now);
           r = ~~(this.c);
           if(d!==r)$(elID).append(txt[r]);
       }
      }
    );     
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks this makes it a lot simpler!!