# Changing state with timeout in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a setState hook inside forEach loop that should update state after each 1000ms

```
    useEffect(() => {
            startTypingAnimation("From past to the future");
    }, []);
```

```
    function startTypingAnimation(sentence) {
        let wordsArr = sentence.split("");
        let animArr = [];

        wordsArr.forEach((item, index) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                animArr.push(item);
                setAnimText(animArr);
                console.log("animArr = ", animArr);
                console.log("animText = ", animText);
            }, 1000 * (index + 1));
        });
    }
```

To make typing effect here:

```
    <Typography variant="h2" align="right">
        {animText}
    </Typography>
```

console.log(animArr) shows expectable behavior, but animText shows undefined in each loop.

**Why am I getting this behavior?**

Comment: where are you declaring animText?

Comment: Hello. What happens when you change the line with setAnimText call to look like this setAnimText(animArr.join('')); . You could be getting this error as you are attempting to display an array? Also state updates happen async so there is that as well.

Comment: Assuming `animText` is the state variable associated with `setAnimText`, its because state does not update immediately, the updated state will only be available on the **next** render. However, the biggest problem is that you're within a `setTimeout` and due to a stale closure the value of `animText` will **never** be updated with a new value.

Comment: 1. animText is declared like let [animText, setAnimText] = useState(); in top of the component
2. When I manually entered values to animText (without timeout) it was ok
3. I thought about that, that's why I asked a question here how to get expected behaviour

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977602/settimeout-not-working-inside-foreach

Comment: State should not be declared as a `let`. It's an antipattern and will only encourage incorrect, mutable behavior. It should always be a `const`. React is designed to work as I've described, and you should not try to circumvent it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately) for more details.

Comment: Ok, thanks to everybody for your answers.

Comment: Off Topic: check this out `for(let i=1; i<=sentence.length; ++i) setTimeout(setAnimText, 1000 * i, sentence.slice(0, i));` or `let part = "", delay = 0; for(let char of sentence) setTimeout(setAnimText, delay += 1000, part += char);`