# Bot not timing out between server members | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

**Aim:** To message everyone in my discord server, but with some sort of cooldown.

**Attempt:** Code

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => {
  setTimeout(function() {
    member.send(argresult).then(console.log(greenBright(`DM'd ${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`))).catch(() => {
    console.error(yellow(`Reattempting to DM member ${member.user.username}#${member.user.discriminator}`))
  })
}, 4000);
...
```

I thought that timing out each member would slow it down but it still kept messaging my members very quickly and not between 4 seconds.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setTimeout not working inside forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977602/settimeout-not-working-inside-foreach)

Answer (score 1):

MassDM Bots are against the Discord ToS and Guildlines due to multiple Reasons.