# How to loop through an array after an interval of 5 second for every value in the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, settimeout

```js
      const array = [
        "aplus",
        "ant",
        "bean",
        "cookie",
        "corncob",
        "corndog",
        "potato",
        "skunk",
        "rabbit",
        "duck",
        "deer",
        "boar",
        "dragon",
        "seaweed",
        "fish",
        "rarefish",
        "exoticfish",
        "jellyfish",
        "legendaryfish",
        "kraken",
        "junk",
        "garbage",
        "trash",
        "worm",
        "ladybug",
        "stickbuy",
        "spider",
        "banhammer",
        "musicalnote",
        "energydrink",
        "memepills",
        "lawdegree",
        "vaccine",
        "beakerofsusfluid",
        "ectoplasm"
      ];
    setTimeout(function(){
      for (const item of array){
    console.log(item);
}
    }, 5000)
```

Is there a way to log all the items in the array after an interval of `5` seconds for each item?

When I try to use an setTimeout function it sends the first value after 5 second and after that it sends all the other values at once..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977602/settimeout-not-working-inside-foreach

Comment: Good find @cmgchess.