# How to add delay between each iteration in Javascript For loop

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a Simon game for FreeCodeCamp and I'm trying to use a for loop to play an audio sound for each piece of the pattern.

The code I have now plays the audio all at once which won't work for the game.  How can I change this code so that it will play each audio sound individually with a .5 second break in between?

Here's the function that plays the audio and adds visual effect

```
function playAudio() {
    if (colorColor === "red") {
      red.play();
      $('#red').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "blue") {
      blue.play();
      $('#blue').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "green") {
      green.play();
      $('#green').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "yellow") {
      yellow.play();
      $('#yellow').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    }
}
```

This is the function where I believe the issue is.

```
function playPattern() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
      colorColor = pattern[i];
      setTimeout(playAudio, 500);
    }
  setTimeout(random, 750);
}
```

And here's the random() function only because it is called within playPattern()

```
function random() {
    randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    colorColor = randomColor;
    colorColor = colorColor.slice(1);
    pattern.push(colorColor);

    count++;
    if (count < 10) {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "0" + count;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
    }

    playAudio();

    pickCount = 0;
    userPick = [];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use `setTimeout(playAudio, i * 500);`

Comment: When the for-loop is executed, all timeouts are set to the same 500ms. So all audio is played at the same time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: I changed it to that code but still doesn't seem to be working properly.

Comment: I read that post and tried the function in the answer but it still wasn't working.

Comment: How long are your audios? Are they all the same length? If yes somethimng like this: `setTimeout(playAudio, (i * (audioLength + 500));` could help you.

Comment: There are many, many duplicates. See [*Javascript, setTimeout loops?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154129/javascript-settimeout-loops) and [*All timers created in loop (with setTimeout) fire at same time?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982293/all-timers-created-in-loop-with-settimeout-fire-at-same-time).

Comment: Do you want the audio files to play in the continuous loop (i.e. looping through colors and repeating)? Do the files have fixed duration?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your audios are all the same length:

```
var audioLength = 3000; // length of audio in ms

for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
  colorColor = pattern[i];
  setTimeout(playAudio, (i * (audioLength + 500));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you are doing:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pattern.length; i++) {
  colorColor = pattern[i];
  setTimeout(playAudio, 500);
}
```

What happens is that you basically define to run `playAudio` in 500ms for all patterns. the for loop is processed immediately and 500ms later all audios are being played together.

What you want is to call the next timeout only when the `playAudio` function ends.

```
let i = 0;
function playAudio() {
    i++;
    colorColor = pattern[i];
    if (colorColor === "red") {
      red.play();
      $('#red').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "blue") {
      blue.play();
      $('#blue').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "green") {
      green.play();
      $('#green').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "yellow") {
      yellow.play();
      $('#yellow').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
    }
    if (i < pattern.length) {
        setTimeout(playAudio, 500);
    }
}

function random() {
    randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    colorColor = randomColor;
    colorColor = colorColor.slice(1);
    pattern.push(colorColor);

    count++;
    if (count < 10) {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "0" + count;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = count;
    }

    playAudio();

    pickCount = 0;
    userPick = [];
}

setTimeout(random, 750);
```

Comment: I didn't exactly use this but it definitely helped me get my answer so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31351186/769326).

What I did was to preload audio files by creating an `object` with the titles as keys and with an object value which contains the files' source and if it's loaded already:

```
const notes = ['do', 're', 'mi', 'fa', 'sol', 'la', 'ti'];
const audioFiles = notes.reduce((obj, title) => {
  obj[title] = {
    src: `notes/${title}.wav`,
    loaded: false,
  };

  return obj;
}, {});

// Preload files.
Object.entries(audioFiles).forEach(([title, details]) => {
  const audio = new Audio();

  audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => {
    details.loaded = true;
  });

  audio.src = details.src;
});
```

The `playPlaylist` function takes a playlist (array of titles) and an object containing the audio files:

```
const playAudio = function playAudio(player, src) {
  player.src = src;
  player.play();
};

const playPlaylist = function playPlaylist(playlist, files) {
  // TODO: Check if files in playlist are already loaded.
  // while (!filesLoaded) { ... }

  const player = new Audio();
  let audioIndex = 0;

  player.addEventListener('ended', () => {
    audioIndex++;

    if (audioIndex >= playlist.length) {
      return;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
      playAudio(player, files[playlist[audioIndex]].src);
    }, 500);
  });

  playAudio(player, files[playlist[audioIndex]].src);
};
```

Then just provide the playlist and pass the audioFiles object.

```
// Play sample playlist.
const playlist = 'do,mi,fa,sol,do,re,la,fa,mi'.split(',');
playPlaylist(playlist, audioFiles);
```

Just change the files and file paths to test.

Answer (score -1):

You need to consider how much the song lasts, and include that on your timeout, for example if red lasts 1 min, you need to set your next timeout to  `setTimeout(blue, 60*1000 + 500)`, something like this :

```
function playAudio(color) {
    if (colorColor === "red") {
      red.play();
      $('#red').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
         playAudio("blue");
      },60*1000 + 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "blue") {
      blue.play();
      $('#blue').effect("highlight", { color: colorColor }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
         playAudio("green");
      },60*1000 + 500);
    } else if (colorColor === "green") {
    //.... ETC
```

You don't need a for, just some recursion